# How to use Xdebug function with PhpStorm?

Tags: xdebug, xdebug-3, phpstorm-2021.1

I have Xdebug setup with PhpStorm. I would like to be able to use some of the Xdebug functions, specially `xdebug_notify()`. That function sends information to the debugging client. However, I don't see it anywhere in the debug window in PhpStorm.

How can I view the `xdebug_notify()` output?

- PhpStorm Version: 2021.3.3
- Xdebug version: 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment (PhpStorm 2022.2) does not have any specific support for `xdebug_notify()`  functionality.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-63456 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified about any progress. So far it has a single vote... (which means: no much interest from the users)